# What are the rules for mixing keyword argument and * tuple in python function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm having difficulty understanding the rules for mixing keyword arguments and *tuple in a python function call

More specifically with the regard to the below code snippet

```
def  func(a,b,c):
    print("These are the arguments",a,b,c)

args = [2]
#Case 1: expected output "These are the arguments:1,2,3" works fine
func(1,c=3,*args)

#Case 2:expected output "These are the arguments:1,3,2" raises TypeError
func(1,b=3,*args)
```

I wanted to understand why  case 1  works but case 2 raises a 
`TypeError: func() got multiple values for argument 'b'`

It looks to me as per the [language reference doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) the above form of mixing of keyword argument and *tuple  is valid. Sorry if i'm missing something obvious.

Tested on 3.4 and 2.7.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyword arguments are not counted when evaluating positional arguments, so in the latter case, you try to provide `b` twice, once with keyword arguments and once with positional arguments. The following method calls are equivalent:

```
func(1, b=3, *args)
func(1, *args, b=3)
```

By the way, a very similar example is shown in the linked documentation just under the frame with CPython implementation details.

Comment: oops it is specified in the  document sorry should have read fully  before posting, thanks for clarifying